# How to fit all of the cards in the same row in SemanticUI?

Tags: html, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-css

I'm trying to make my cards all appear on the same row and at the same time be linked. But I can't find a way to achieve both. I've tried tweaking the elements of the card, the image size, container width, card width - nothing worked.
[current version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z54qy.jpg)
Here's the code that keeps the last card from slipping to the next row :

```
<body>

<div class = "ui container">

<div class="ui top attached menu">
   ....
</div>
<div class="ui bottom attached  item active segment">
        <header>
    <h2>Favorite Albums<br> <small>Of different genres </small></h2>
</header>
<br>
<main class="ui equal width stackable grid">
    <section class="ui row">
    <div class="ui card column"> <div class="image">
    <img src="Images/Demondays.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="header">Demon Days </div>
      <span class="meta"> Gorillaz</span>
    <div class="description">
    The album's style is a strong foray into the melding of hip hop into pop and rock music. The British Pop at it's finest.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
      <span class=" date"> 
      <i class=" left floated microphone icon"></i>
      15 Songs </span>
   
       <a class="right floated" href="https://open.spotify.com/album/0bUTHlWbkSQysoM3VsWldT?si=NyjMo8ovQmWTqi4DM1zeCA">
         <button class="ui mini positive button"><i class="spotify icon"></i>Listen on Spotify</button>
      </a>
  </div>          
     </div>
       
 
 
    <div class="ui card column"> <div class="image">
    <img src="images/Demondays.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="header">Demon Days </div>
      <span class="meta"> Gorillaz</span>
    <div class="description">
    The album's style is a strong foray into the melding of hip hop into pop and rock music. The British Pop at it's finest.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
      <span class=" date"> 
      <i class=" left floated microphone icon"></i>
      15 Songs </span>
   
       <a class="right floated" href="https://open.spotify.com/album/0bUTHlWbkSQysoM3VsWldT?si=NyjMo8ovQmWTqi4DM1zeCA">
         <button class="ui mini positive button"><i class="spotify icon"></i>Listen on Spotify</button>
      </a>
  </div>          
     </div>
        <div class="ui card column"> <div class="image">
    <img src="images/Demondays.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="header">Demon Days </div>
      <span class="meta"> Gorillaz</span>
    <div class="description">
    The album's style is a strong foray into the melding of hip hop into pop and rock music. The British Pop at it's finest.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
      <span class=" date"> 
      <i class=" left floated microphone icon"></i>
      15 Songs </span>
   
       <a class="right floated" href="https://open.spotify.com/album/0bUTHlWbkSQysoM3VsWldT?si=NyjMo8ovQmWTqi4DM1zeCA">
         <button class="ui mini positive button"><i class="spotify icon"></i>Listen on Spotify</button>
      </a>
  </div>          
     </div>
      <div class="ui card column"> <div class="image">
    <img src="images/Demondays.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="header">Demon Days </div>
      <span class="meta"> Gorillaz</span>
    <div class="description">
    The album's style is a strong foray into the melding of hip hop into pop and rock music. The British Pop at it's finest.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
      <span class=" date"> 
      <i class=" left floated microphone icon"></i>
      15 Songs </span>
   
       <a class="right floated" href="https://open.spotify.com/album/0bUTHlWbkSQysoM3VsWldT?si=NyjMo8ovQmWTqi4DM1zeCA">
         <button class="ui mini positive button"><i class="spotify icon"></i>Listen on Spotify</button>
      </a>
  </div>          
     </div>
 
  
     </section>
       </main>
    </div> </div>
<script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<script  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.5.0/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

If I add `<div class="ui link cards>` after the row segment they won't stack on the same row but the animation when you hover works. How can I keep the animation and keep them on the same row and have some space in between them? I guess the container and body have to be different but I'd like to keep this layout if possible.